# Django form not receiving user object

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make a change password form for a user who knows his password and can login, but wants to change it. I made up a form and stuff, but it doesn't seem to pass the user object into the form, as it says it's a NoneType Object.

```
#forms.py
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    error_messages = {
        'wrong_current': _("You did not enter the right password!"),
        'invalid_new': _("You have entered an invalid new password or you did not enter one!"),
        'no_match': _("The new passwords do not match!")
    }
    current_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="New Password: ")
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Repeat New Password: ")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        print self.user
        super(ChangePasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        try:
            a = u.objects.get(username__iexact=self.user)
        except u.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        if self.cleaned_data['new_password1'] != self.cleaned_data['new_password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['no_match'])
        if a.check_password(self.cleaned_data["current_password"]) == "False":
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages["wrong_current"])
        return self.cleaned_data
#views.py
def change_pass_view(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = u.objects.get(username__iexact=request.user)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data["new_password1"])
            user.save()
        else:
            print "invalid"
            a = request.user
            a = u.objects.get(username__iexact=a)
            form = UserModificationForm(instance=a)
            form2 = ChangeEmailForm()
            form3 = ChangePasswordForm(user=request.user)
            return render(request, 'accounts/modify.html', {'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'form3': form3, 'usr':request.user, 'email':request.user.email})
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

I need some help greatly!

Comment: you forgot to pass user in first ChangePasswordForm form

Comment: I did forget, but adding does not fix it. Also u is the variable for get_user_model()

Comment: traceback: http://dpaste.com/1352340/

Comment: What does say your print statements?

Comment: Well if  I print errors, it says invalid, but the issue is known, which is the form is not receiving the current user. The problem is that I am passing the current user, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was not aware that there was already a pre-made form for what I wanted in django. It works perfectly now.